# How to tackle the screaming/tantrum of a 6-month-old boy?

Tags: infant, discipline, tantrums, grandparents

My 6-month-old grandson wants to watch the the "VuVu" video while eating. So he starts to scream loudly and crazily, almost like e tantrum, just to watch that while eating. Any suggestions as to how to tackle him?

Comment: Please consider adding some information, such as how often you feed the baby, if he lives with you, who sets the rules, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

One.

Don't watch it. Ever. Again. (or at least for a year and a half).

He's too young for the *real* tantrums, he just wants something and shows it. When he screams, let him. Talk to him in a calm manner, and try to change the subject. A favorite puppet doing something funny, a book, anything that will make him forget about watching the show will be good.

After 3-4 days of consistently not watching while eating he should start acting normally.

Moreover, I suggest that you tell him that the TV is broken (remove batteries from the remote and show him that it isn't working) and not watch it again unless he's asleep or outside. [Children shouldn't be watching TV before being 2 years old!](https://www.healthychildren.org/English/family-life/Media/Pages/Why-to-Avoid-TV-Before-Age-2.aspx)

Comment: I agree with much of what you say, but this is a grandparent asking. What to do if grandparent is not in control most of the time? Maybe I should be clarifying with the OP...

Comment: You are obviously right, my answer's based on the question as it stands. If there are any clarifications, I'll try to update the answer.

Comment: +1000 for do not watch it. Giving in now will set a trend for tantrums well into his toddler years. It seems likely that someone has already given in to this screaming and has accidentally encouraged it. Now you must wait it out. Its hard but well worth it to avoid this behavior in an older child.